# How to rollback function in node js if error occur using mysql in node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

how to combine these three functions.And compdb() and pardb() works with dynamic array.

function marketdb(sellwalletamount, custId, receivedamount) {

```
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        let sql1 = "SELECT * FROM pair_master WHERE id ='" + req.body.pair_id + "'";
        connection.query(sql1, function(error, pairdata) {
            if (error) {

                reject(error)
            } else {
                if (pairdata[0] == null || pairdata[0] == undefined) {

                    reject(error);
                } else {
                    let sql2 = "SELECT * FROM customer_wallet WHERE customer_id ='" + custId + "'AND currency_code='" + pairdata[0].to + "'";
                    connection.query(sql2, function(error, receivewalletdata) {
                        if (error) {

                            reject(error);
                        } else {

                            if (receivewalletdata[0] == null || receivewalletdata == undefined) {
                                console.log({ success: false, message: "received wallet not found" });
                                reject(error);
                            } else {


                                var addmoney = receivewalletdata[0].total_amount + receivedamount;

                                let sql3 = "UPDATE customer_wallet SET total_amount ='" + addmoney + "' WHERE customer_id='" + custId + "'AND currency_code='" + pairdata[0].to + "'";
                                connection.query(sql3, function(error, response) {
                                    if (error) {
                                        console.log({ success: false, message: "Error", error: error });
                                        reject(error);

                                    } else {
                                        var presentBalance = sellwalletamount - req.body.quantity;

                                        let sql4 = "UPDATE customer_wallet SET total_amount ='" + presentBalance + "' WHERE customer_id='" + custId + "'AND currency_code='" + pairdata[0].from + "'";

                                        connection.query(sql4, function(error, final) {
                                            if (error) {
                                                console.log({ success: false, message: "Error", error: error });
                                                reject(error);

                                            } else {


                                                let sql5 = "INSERT INTO transaction_master (status,trade_type,type,customer_id,avg_price,created_at) values ('Fully Executed','Sell','Market','" + custId + "','" + receivedamount + "','" + created_at + "');"

                                                connection.query(sql5, function(err, transmasterid) {
                                                    if (err) {
                                                        reject(error);

                                                    } else {

                                                        resolve(transmasterid.insertId) 
                                                    }
                                                })

                                            }
                                        })
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    })
}




function compdb(dedd, mcustId, custtranmastId) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        var i = dedd.length
        console.log("i in complte save", i)
        async.forEachOf(dedd, function(error, i, inner_callback) {
                let sql1 = "UPDATE buy SET status = 'Fully Executed' WHERE id ='" + dedd[i].trade_id + "'";
                console.log(sql1)
                connection.query(sql1, function(err, rows, fields) {
                    if (!err) {

                        console.log("done")
                        console.log(dedd.trade_id)
                        let sql = "Select*from transaction_master where trade_type ='Buy' and trade_id='" + dedd[i].trade_id + "'";
                        console.log(sql)
                        connection.query(sql, function(err, transactionmasterdata) {
                            if (err) {

                                inner_callback(err);
                            } else if (transactionmasterdata[0] == null || transactionmasterdata[0] == undefined) {
                                console.log(transactionmasterdata)
                                let sql2 = "INSERT INTO transaction_master (status,trade_type,type,trade_id,customer_id,avg_price,created_at) values ('Fully Executed','Buy','Limit','" + dedd[i].trade_id + "','" + dedd[i].customer_id + "','" + dedd[i].money + "','" + created_at + "');"

                                connection.query(sql2, function(err, results) {
                                    if (!err) {


                                        let sql4 = "INSERT INTO transaction (customer_id,trade_type,type,trade_id,to_from_customer_id,price,quantity,status,pair_id,created_at,transanction_master_id) values ('" + dedd[i].customer_id + "','Buy','Limit','" + dedd[i].trade_id + "','" + mcustId + "','" + dedd[i].money + "','" + dedd[i].quantity + "','Fully Executed','" + dedd[i].pair_id + "','" + created_at + "','" + results.insertId + "'),('" + mcustId + "','Sell','Market','" + dedd[i].trade_id + "','" + dedd[i].customer_id + "','" + dedd[i].money + "','" + dedd[i].quantity + "','Fully Executed','" + dedd[i].pair_id + "','" + created_at + "','" + custtranmastId + "');"

                                        connection.query(sql4, function(err, rows, fields) {
                                            if (!err) {


                                                inner_callback(null);
                                            } else {

                                                inner_callback(err);
                                            };
                                        });
                                    } else {

                                        inner_callback(err);
                                    }
                                })
                            } else {

                                var newavg_price = (transactionmasterdata[0].avg_price + dedd[i].money) / 2;

                                let sql2 = "UPDATE transaction_master SET status='Fully Executed',avg_price='" + newavg_price + "' where id= '" + transactionmasterdata[0].id + "'";

                                connection.query(sql2, function(err, results) {
                                    if (!err) {


                                        let sql4 = "INSERT INTO transaction (customer_id,trade_type,type,trade_id,to_from_customer_id,price,quantity,status,pair_id,created_at,transanction_master_id) values ('" + dedd[i].customer_id + "','Buy','Limit','" + dedd[i].trade_id + "','" + mcustId + "','" + dedd[i].money + "','" + dedd[i].quantity + "','Fully Executed','" + dedd[i].pair_id + "','" + created_at + "','" + transactionmasterdata[0].id + "'),('" + mcustId + "','Sell','Market','" + dedd[i].trade_id + "','" + dedd[i].customer_id + "','" + dedd[i].money + "','" + dedd[i].quantity + "','Fully Executed','" + dedd[i].pair_id + "','" + created_at + "','" + transactionmasterdata[0].id + "');"

                                        connection.query(sql4, function(err, rows, fields) {
                                            if (!err) {


                                                inner_callback(null);
                                            } else {

                                                inner_callback(err);
                                            };
                                        });
                                    } else {

                                        inner_callback(err);
                                    }
                                })

                            }
                        })
                    } else {

                        inner_callback(err);

                    }
                })
            },
            function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err)

                    console.log(err)
                } else {
                    resolve("ok")

                }
            });
    })
}



function pardb(dedd, mcustId) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        var i = dedd.length
        async.forEachOf(dedd, function(error, i, inner_callback) {
                let sql1 = "UPDATE buy SET status = 'Partially Executed',quantity='" + dedd[i].newquantity + "' WHERE id ='" + dedd[i].trade_id + "'";

                connection.query(sql1, function(err, rows, fields) {
                    if (!err) {

                        console.log("done")
                        //inner_callback(null);
                        let sql2 = "INSERT INTO transaction (customer_id,trade_type,type,trade_id,to_from_customer_id,price,quantity,status,pair_id,created_at) values ('" + dedd[i].customer_id + "','Buy','Limit'," + dedd[i].trade_id + "','" + mcustId + "','" + dedd[i].money + "','" + dedd[i].quantity + "','Partially Executed','" + dedd[i].pair_id + "','" + created_at + "'),('" + mcustId + "','Sell','Market'," + dedd[i].trade_id + "','" + dedd.customer_id + "','" + dedd[i].money + "','" + dedd[i].quantity + "','Partially Executed','" + dedd[i].pair_id + "','" + created_at + "');"



                        connection.query(sql2, function(err, rows, fields) {
                            if (!err) {

                                inner_callback(null);
                            } else {

                                inner_callback(err);
                            };
                        });
                    } else {

                        inner_callback(err);

                    }
                })
            },
            function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err)


                } else {
                    resolve("ok")


                }
            });
    })
}
```

How to merge these three function into one and also if error occur rollback all functions in node js.All functions working fine one after another but i have to include rollback all function in case of error.
First function change status only fro a single user.
second function works with array and change status of all the user presently in the array.
third function also do the same as second but with different status

Comment: Step 1.  Research what a "transaction" is  https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#transactions.  Step 2.  Please tell me you're not going to use that implementation... all that nesting is worse than call-back hell on steroids.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes I have to use this implementation. Is there is any other way to not to use nesting.Please help me if you know how to code in better  way. and yes i already try "transaction" in this code but cannt found any result.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to use [sequelize.js](https://sequelize.org/master/). It is much easier and more understandable. There is a section called [transactions](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/transactions.html) which has all the information you need to implement a transaction (including commits and rollbacks). But before you dive into this middleware, I suggest you to read about [Promise chains](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining). Generally, you commit the transaction at the final `then` and rollback at the `catch error` section.
In other words, when everything is OK, transaction will be committed and if an error occurs, the whole chain will be rolled back to whatever it was. This is a simple example:

```
sequelize.transaction().then(async transaction => {
    // firstPromise (you should pass transaction inside the query function)
  .then(()=>{
    // second promise
    // you can return a value from this promise to the next one
  })
  .then(()=>{
    // third  promise
  })
  .then(()=>{
    // final state
    transaction.commit();
  })
  .catch(err => {
      transaction.rollback();
  });
});
```